# Separated reverse proxy per user on apache2.4

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, user-management

From [mod_proxy guide](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_proxy.html) I configured reverse proxy with user authentication.

```
# Set reverse proxy
ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:10080/"
ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://localhost:10080/"
ProxyRequests On
ProxyVia On

<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Password Required"
    AuthUserFile /home/secure/.passwords
    Require user ivy
</Proxy>
```

This works as following:
User accesses to the server --> Server asks username/password --> User enters his credentials --> If credentials are OK for user ivy then reverse proxy works for port 10080 on local host.

All users are added with htpasswd. I run apache2.4 over Linux.

What I need to do:
I want allow different users using the proxying. On the server number of reverse tunnels are open with ports 10080, 10081, 10082, and so on...
I want to assign every single user to use separated proxy port. I.e.:

- ivy --> 10080
- joe --> 10081
- doe --> 10082

If I write `Require user ivy joe doe` then I redirect all users into single port 10080.

It seems the trick is somewhere in lines `ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:10080/"` and `<Proxy *>`. Or where?

**Update:**
Following Jenny's suggestion tried:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteCond %{REMOTE_USER} ivy  # Unconditional redirect for testing.
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ "http://localhost:10080/test.html" [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Tried this with Proxy enabled (proxy is stronger than Rewrite) and Proxy disabled (Local index.html displayed).

Tried use flags `[R,L]`, `[L,R]`, `[L,R=301]` - no luck.

Tried to add into `<Directory "/var/www/html">` and into `<Proxy *>`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ "http://localhost:10080/test.html" [R=301,L]
```

Tried this with Proxy enabled (proxy is stronger than Rewrite) and Proxy disabled (Local index.html displayed).

Deep dig found this trick:

```
RedirectMatch ^/.*$ /test.html
```

This works but this is not conditional: i.e. I still can't assign different redirect per user.

**Update2:**
Tried solution of Cedric Knight with no luck too. Decided to give up with Apache, switched to nginx. Works OK. The server configuration for separated reverse proxy per user is:

```
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80  default_server ipv6only=on;
    set $auth_status 100;
    server_name  localhost;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        auth_basic "Restricted content";
        auth_basic_user_file "/home/secure/.passwords";
        auth_request_set $auth_status $upstream_status;

        if ($remote_user = "ivy") {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:10080;
            break;  # break is essential since proxy_pass in 'if' isn't allowed.
        }
        if ($remote_user = "joe") {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:10081;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is brute-force solution. In next step, I'll add reading the map user:port from file.

Comment: You could probably do this with mod_rewrite using a mapping table.

Comment: Thank you, Jenny. I tried what I could understand from the Internet with no success meanwhile. Updated the question.

Comment: "mod_rewrite using a mapping table." Was my initial thoughts. Dunno what to add here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Jenny's idea makes sense.  Don't use the ProxyPass directive, just use [mod_proxy via mod_rewrite using the P flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p) then you can as a next stage set [additional users up](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/rewritemap.html) with `RewriteMap`.

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_USER} ivy
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ "http://localhost:10080/$1" [P]
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_USER} joe
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ "http://localhost:10081/$1" [P]
    #etc.
    # optional step: set up RewriteMap
    RewriteMap user-to-port txt:/home/proxy-ports.txt
    # contains one entry per line 'doe 10082' etc
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_USER} ^(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ "http://localhost:${user-to-port:%1|10080}/$1" [P]
    # 10080 is default port for other users
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

And if you get rid of the `<Proxy>` section, separate out the authentication challenge accordingly, using Apache 2.4 directives:

```
<Location "/">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Password Required"
    AuthUserFile /home/secure/.passwords
    <RequireAll>
        Require valid-user
    </RequireAll>
</Location>
```

I don't see the need for `ProxyVia` in a reverse proxy situation; although you might want to log local and remote ports.  I've not tested any of the above, just wanted to suggest a direction for what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you, Cedric. Proposed configuration makes many things clear. I copied it into my config file and tried to run it using `<Proxy>` section and without it, using `<Location "/">`. Unfortunately, no fortune. Fortunately, I decided to switch from Apache to nginx and managed to learn it and implement everything just reading common examples. Thank you again for help.